# How do I add a row to a 2D array?

Tags: java, arrays

```
String loginInfo[][] = { { "mason", "dragon"   }, //First Column is usernames, second is passwords.
                         { "shay",  "stowers"  }, 
                         { "admin", "password" }, };
```

This is my array that has the username in the first col, passwords in the second col. I want to be able to add another row to this array once a user has submitted two strings.

Example...

String input1 = "username", String input2 = "password";

I want to take these two Strings and add them as a row, to the array. So my end result would look like this..

```
String loginInfo[][] = { { "mason",    "dragon"   },
                         { "shay",     "stowers"  },
                         { "admin",    "password" },
                         { "username", "password" }, };//This coming from input1 and input2
```

Comment: You can't... arrays are of _fixed length_. you'd better take a look at the `java.util.Collections` Framework.

Comment: Arrays are fixed-size, so you can't add to the original one. You need to make a new array that's at least one size bigger. A much better solution would be to use an `List<List<String>>`.

Comment: Take a look at `Map` in the `Collections API`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perfect place to use an ArrayList of your user information JavaBean like

```
List<UserInfo> userInfo = new ArrayList<UserInfo>();
```

Whenever you receive `userName` and `passWord`, create an instance of `UserInfo` and add it to the list

`UserInfo` Class like below

```
class UserInfo{

 private String userName = null;

 private String passWord = null;

 // add a constructor
 public UserInfo(String userName, String passWord){
  this.userName = userName;
  this.passWord = passWord; 
 }

 //add setters and getters
 ...
 ...

}
```

Check it out. You will like it

Disclaimer : Not tested. Just a prototype!

Comment: Perhaps u could give a _simple structure_ of the `UserInfo` class to the OP.

Comment: Well done... too bad I can offer only one upvote. :-)

Comment: Thanks, we haven't yet delved into multiple classes yet so I think I'll just stick to 2 lists for now, one for usernames and one for passwords.

Comment: No, Please create an object (Javabean) to store both username and password collectively and have a single list. This will keep your data organised.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are not changeable.  They are the length they are originally given.  You have two options:

1. Create a new array, increasing its length, then copy the old array into the new one.
2. Use a collection in which Java has already done all this for you.  Check out Lists.

EDIT:
Example for option 1:

```
string[ ][ ] newloginInfo = new int[loginInfo.length * 2][2];

for (int i = 0; i < loginInfo.length; i++) {
    System.arraycopy(loginInfo[i], 0, newloginInfo[i], 0, loginInfo[0].length);
}

//now there is room for twice as many rows.  Add as usual.
```

Example for option 2:
simply use the Generic list instead of the array to being with:

```
List<List<of string>> list = new ArrayList<List<of String>();
```

then you just call list.add to add in a new array:

```
List<of string> newrow = new ArrayList<of string>();
list.add(newrow);
```

apologies - not tested or thrown in an ide - check the syntax.

EDIT 2:
Octopus's suggestion of having an object and then storing a list of those objects is really the way to go instead of dealing with multidimensional arrays - unless you have a REALLY good reason not you use it.  It's cleaner, more organized, and your IDE will pick up the details in intellisense.